# PHP mailer error in xampp local server

Tags: php, email

Trying to send email through PHP mailer from local xampp but getting error:

1. SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
2. SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.
3. The following From address failed: azadlm460@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted from server,530,5.5.1

Code is:

```
    <?php   
function sendOTP($clientemail,$num) {
    require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');


$message_body = "One Time Password for PHP login authentication is:<br/><br/>" . $num;

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "Azad";
$mail->Password = "mypass";
$mail->SetFrom("myemail");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("anotheremail");

    if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else{
    echo "Message has been sent";
    }

}
?>
```

Already tried:

Added PHP mailer in root.

Allow access for less secure apps.

Changed password for gmail.

Account access enabled.

Comment: Try changing port to 587 and smtp secure to tls

Comment: @Vishal same error.

Comment: Check if you are able to reach to smtp server using telnet smtp.gmail.com 587

Comment: does your gmail account is enables thrid party access from the account setting/options?